# how to eliminates all letters ch1 which also appear ch2 (language c)

Tags: c

Write a program that reads two strings of characters CH1 and CH2 on the keyboard and eliminates all the letters of CH1 which also appear in CH2.
Note: without using pointer and strcpy.

Could you please tell me why the characters aren't shifting correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char ch1[30], ch2[30], ch3[30];
    int i, j, L1, L2, X;

    printf("please enter ch1: ");
    scanf("%s",ch1);
    printf("please enter ch2 : ");
    scanf("%s",ch2);

    L1=strlen(ch1);
    L2=strlen(ch2);

    for(i=0;i<L1;i++)
        X=0;
        for(j=0;j<L2;j++){
            if(ch1[i]==ch2[j]){
                X=1;
                ch1[i]=ch1[i+1];
            } 
        }
    printf("result : %s" , ch1);
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: You've not explained a problem or asked a question. This is a question and answer site. In order to get an answer, there needs to be a *clear problem description* and a *specific question*. You've posted your assignment and dumped your code. Pasting your assignment is the problem *you* were given, but you've not explained a problem related to the code you've posted, or asked a question about that problem yet.

Comment: The temptation to post a [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg) solution is almost too strong to resist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char ch1[30], ch2[30], ch3[30];
    int i, j, L1, L2, X, k;

    printf("veuillez saisir ch1: \n");
    scanf("%s",ch1);
    printf("veuillez saisir ch2 : \n");
    scanf("%s",ch2);

    L1=strlen(ch1);
    L2=strlen(ch2);

    for(i=0;i<L1;i++)
        for(j=0;j<L2;j++){
            if(ch1[i]==ch2[j]){
                for(k = i; k < L1 - 1; k++) {
                    ch1[k]=ch1[k+1];
                }
                i--;
                L1--;
                ch1[L1] = '\0';
                for(k = j; k < L2 - 1; k++) {
                    ch2[k]=ch2[k+1];
                }
                L2--;
                ch2[L2] = '\0';
                break;
            } 
        }
    printf("Chaîne résultat : %s\n" , ch1);

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm basically doing is shifting the string down every time I find a char in ch1 which is in ch2. And then I'm null terminating the string so it prints correctly and reducing the size by 1.

Comment: thank you for that, but this is not what i want i will give you an exemple:
abacab   aa        ==>  bcab

Comment: @SamiirTafrout can you vote my answer as correct, please.  Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think you're trying to use `X` as a `skip` flag. Rename it.

You will have to reset that flag inside the `i` loop, as it will possibly have a different value for each letter.

```
for (i...) {
    skip_this_letter = 0;

    for (j...) {
        if (...) {
            skip_this_letter = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!skip_this_letter) {
        // copy letter
```